# Reusing MySQL prepared statements in PHP classes

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I have a PHP class that uses a MySQLi prepared statement to load some data like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a, $bla;
    public load(&$mysqli) {
        $s = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT a FROM x WHERE y = ?');
        $s->bind_param('s', $this->bla);
        $s->bind_result($this->a);

        if($s->execute()) {
            if($s->fetch()) {
                $s->free_result();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this means that for every object of MyClass on which I call the load() function I will prepare a new statement, which seems inefficient.

My idea for reusing the prepared statement would be to do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a, $bla;
    private static $my_s;

    public load(&$mysqli) {
        if(!self::$my_s) {
            self::$my_s = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT a FROM x WHERE y = ?');
        }

        $s = self::$my_s;
        $s->bind_param('s', $this->bla);
        $s->bind_result($this->a);

        if($s->execute()) {
            if($s->fetch()) {
                $s->free_result();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So save the statement as a static member variable. This way, the statement should be prepared the first time I call load(), after which it will be reused by all objects of the same class.

Is this a valid approach? Is there a better way?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, the "better" way depends on your code requirements and architecture. I think you'd be better reading about "php reusable db class" and such searches here and Google. When you have final code, put it on Code Review (if it fits their requirements etc)

Comment: If you're going to use an object then you could prepare in the constructor, if you're always going to need that same statement.

Comment: Unfortunately this is code I am adding to a massive old codebase, so I can't do much in terms of redesigning the code. I don't want to add this to the constructor because I won't actually need to perform this query every time, so I also don't want to prepare the statement before I have to.